# rails: how to use database bindings in where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, parameters, sql-injection, where-clause

in rails, if i try to get an object using where:

```
Customer.where(:name => "abc")
```

the log file shows that no database bindings are used.

```
WHERE "apps"."name" = 'abc'
```

Now if i create a new object

```
Customer.create(:name => "abc", :field => 1)
```

rails uses parameters

```
INSERT INTO "customers" ("name", "field") VALUES (?, ?)
```

how can i get rails to use database parameter bindings in where as well?

The following statement also generates the same where

Customer.where("name = ?", "abc")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 3.1, prepared statements are used, so you will see queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.name = ? [["name", "abc"]]
```

As far as I know, this works for Postgres and not MySql.

You needn't worry about SQL injection, in any case.  Please read about the protections against SQL injection that are built-in to Rails:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: If this is the case, looks like an ORM thing where the performance gains of using placeholders for `WHERE` clauses is marginal, yet for things like repeated `INSERT` statements it is worth it. A prepared statement is not a zero-cost thing.

Comment: @Sean - i am using for dev sqlite, but still i see the prepared statements for create but not for where

Comment: @tadman - i am more concerned with security. the performance gain would be minimal as you say

Comment: @tadman, please see this article for more info on prepared statements in Rails 3.1: http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/22/show-some-love-for-prepared-statements-in-rails-3-1

Comment: @Sean - so if i use .where("name = ?", "abc") that should be from a security point of view?

Comment: You can use `.where(:name => "abc")` or `.where("name = ?", "abc")`.  Both are correct.  The important thing is that you allow Rails to do the binding.  DO NOT do something like `.where("name = #{params[:foo]}")`, as that will leave you vulnerable.  Instead, you would do `.where(:name => params[:foo])` or the form with the question mark.